# An extra length appear on the first vline(|) that I havent stated in table

Tags: tables, tabularx

When I use the tabular environment the lenght of the first vline exceeds the table size, this is the code Im using and finally an image of the output.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c c|c c|} \hline
$\Omega $&$ 0.000025$ & $\tau$&$ -0.1$\\
$\phi $&$0.55$ & $\rho$ & $0.025$\\
$q_1$&$0.5$ & $q_2$ & $0.5$\\
$k_1$&$12000$ & $\lambda$&$0.1$\\
$k_2$&$700$ & $\delta$&$0.1$\\
\hline \label{valoresparametros}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is due to your `\label`. Use it with  `\captionof 'table}{Some caption}`, outside of `tabular`.

Comment: You don't label `tabular`, but a `\caption`.